# How to compile 64 bit apache modules on CentOS?

Tags: centos, apache-2.2

I've tried to install mod_passenger on a 64 bit CentOS5.3 machine and the module compiles into a 32 bit `.so` file. Followed standard recipe: `gem install passenger; passenger-install-apache2-module`.

- apache 2.2.3
- Rails 2.3.5
- gem 1.35

The `passenger-install-apache2-module` command emits a script (while running it) with lot's of flags like `-m32` and `-march=i386`. I've captured the script, replaced `-m32` with `-m64` and `-march=i386` with `-march=x86_64`, re-ran it (with some extra include path and `APXS2` variables) but the output object is still in 32 bit format.

Could someone share insight on how to force the 64-bitness upon the passenger?

**edit:** later I found out that any module I would try to compile would be built into a 32 bit version, so it's not specific to passenger

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer finally - uninstalling `apr.i386` solved this problem

```
yum remove apr.i386
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as solved.

Comment: I was beating my brains out installing Passenger until I found this. Thank you!